# Powermockito whenNew returns null if not matched

Tags: java, testing, mockito, powermock

I do not know if it supposed to do that, but I guess not. Have a look to my code below.

```
File mocked = PowerMockito.mock(File.class);    
PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withParameterTypes(String.class).withArguments(eq(THE_TARGET_PATH)).thenReturn(mocked);
File normalFile = new File(WORKING_PATH);
File mockedFile = new File(THE_TARGET_PATH);
```

I do expect that the `normalFile` will be created normally, but it is actually `null`. The `mockedFile` is mocked correctly btw.

I am also using `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest({ClassWhereInstanceIsCreated.class, File.class})`

and I am using:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My finding shows that there is no good way to do partial constructor mocking with PowerMockito / PowerMockito 2. By the logic you should be able to do something like

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withParameterTypes(String.class)
                                .withArguments(eq(WORKING_PATH)).thenCallRealMethod();
```

But this will trigger internal exception in the PowerMockito similar to this

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Cannot call abstract real method on java object! Calling real methods is only possible when mocking non abstract method. //correct example: when(mockOfConcreteClass.nonAbstractMethod()).thenCallRealMethod();

Thus, the only way I can see is to re-write the test. You should construct all your required `File` objects first, before mocking constructor and give PowerMockito rules which to return in each particualr case.

```
File mocked = Mockito.mock(File.class);
// create file as you want
File realFile = new File(WORKING_PATH);
// tell PowerMockito to return it
PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withParameterTypes(String.class)
            .withArguments(Mockito.eq(WORKING_PATH)).thenReturn(realFile);
// tell PowerMockito to return mock if other argument passed
PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withParameterTypes(String.class)
            .withArguments(Mockito.eq(THE_TARGET_PATH)).thenReturn(mocked);

File normalFile = new File(WORKING_PATH);
File mockedFile = new File(THE_TARGET_PATH);
```

This is undesirable solution, but I could not offer anything better.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thx, I am already doing this 'workaround'. It seems that the Powermock is not able to do it any better. But still, let's wait for more answers before I mark this answer as accepted.